# TableView в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

```
    public TableColumn<Person, Integer> num = new TableColumn<>();
    public TableColumn<Person, String> fName = new TableColumn<>();
    public TableColumn<Person, LocalDate> bDay = new TableColumn<>();
    public TableColumn<Person, String> lastJob = new TableColumn<>();
    public TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<Person>();
```

Есть правильно заполненный person экземпляр класса Person.
Колонки и таблица связаны с fxml файлом.

```
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    Parent root = null;
                    try {
                        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("table.fxml"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    list.add(person);
                    tableView.setItems(list);
                    stage.setTitle("Select the employee");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
                    stage.setResizable(true);
                    stage.show();
```

Пытаюсь добавить в таблицу persona, но ничего не выходить, при открытии окна таблица пустая.